# JS undefined and NULL checker not working

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, undefined

```
     for(const id of this.extraRooms)
            {
              let doesRoomExist = document.getElementById('newRoomAddress' + newRoomId);
              //if(typeof(doesRoomExist) !== "null")              
               if(typeof(doesRoomExist) !== "undefined")
              {
                  const newRoomLabel = document.getElementById('newRoomAddress' + newRoomId).value        
             {
```

Probably a simple fix but if doesRoomExist is NULL it is still going inside the if statement...

```
let doesRoomExist = document.getElementById('newRoomAddress' + newRoomId);
```

will show doesRoomExist  as NULL when stepping through the code in VS code, but show as undefined if used in developer tools...why is it going inside the if?

any help please?

Comment: Run `typeof null` in a Javascript debugger to understand your issue. All you need to do is  `if(doesRoomExist) {...}` - research Javascript truthiness.

Comment: Because `typoeof something` will never be `"null"` use `if (doesRoomExist !== null)` or simply `if (doesRoomExist)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the value of `doesRoomExist` directly not its type, you can either check `if (doesRoomExist !== null)` or just doing `if (doesRoomExist)` will be enough;

```js
if(doesRoomExist !== null)
    const newRoomLabel = document.getElementById('newRoomAddress' + newRoomId).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if (doesRoomExist) { /*...*/ }`.

```js
for (const id of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
  const doesExist = document.getElementById('item' + id);
  if (doesExist) {
    const newLabel = document.getElementById('item' + id).value;
    console.log(newLabel);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="item1" value="value1">
<input id="item2" value="value2">
<input id="item4" value="value4">
<input id="item5" value="value5">
```